# I can't quite understand the meaning of 自分でも

Tags: grammar

I can't quite derive the meaning of 自分でも from the parts that make it up.

Here are the example sentences I don't get with the offered translations.

> 自分でもそれをやってみます。       Do it by yourself.
>
> 自分でもそれが解っているんだけと。   I know it myself.

Are the translations wrong?
Why is there a も there? There doesn't seem to be an "Even" or a "Too" nuance in the sentences.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I'd also appreciate an answer that clarified if this でも is で＋も or でも and what difference would it make if the も was dropped.

Comment: The first translation is definitely wrong, that's not an imperative/request at all. Where do they come from?

Comment: From Anki. And yeah I know that it's not a request, I was thinking more like a verb and it's auxiliary information "Go for a run". Just a statement of action rather than an imperative.

Still, it does sound wrong.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Despite the way it is written, it probably was not intended as an imperative, eg "(You may/can) do it by yourself."  I'd also appreciate an answer that clarified if this でも is で＋も or でも and what difference would it make if the も was dropped.

Comment: I added your question in @Tim

Comment: The Tanaka corpus (known to be full of errors, mind you) has these three sentences: (1) 「自分でもそれが解っているんだけと。」 = "I know it myself."　　 (2) 「自分でもそれをやってみなさい。」 = "Do it by yourself."　　 (3) 「自分でもそれをやってみます。」 = "I'll do it by myself too."　　You've supplied sentences 1 and 3 with the translations for 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, to break things down into parts...

> 自分でもそれをやってみます。

【自分】oneself / myself

【で】by (preposition)

【も】too

【それをやってみます】 will try to do it

For pure comprehension purposes, this can be made easier to understand by replacing【自分でも】with【私も】＋【自分で】

e.g.【私も自分でそれをやってみます。】
Effectively, "I too, will try to do it by myself." (As opposed to leaving the task up to someone else to do.)

If the も was dropped remove "too, " from the above phrase.

> 自分でもそれが解っているんだけと。

(Note: I will assume a typo and that the final と is supposed to be ど)

【自分】I / myself (personal pronoun)

【でも】even (adverb)

【それが解っているん】understand that

【だけど】([conjunction] to an omitted phrase or [emphasis] depending on the nuance)

Effectively, either...

[Conjunction] "Even though I understand that..." (Omitted phrase understood by context)
For example: 
A「タバコをやめるべきですよ。体に悪いんです。」B「自分でもそれがわかっているんだけど・・・（やめられないんだよ）」

[Emphasis] "Even I understand that !／? (don't treat me like a fool)"
For example: 
A「空が青いって知ってますか？」B「私でもそれがわかっているんだけど（バカにしないでください）」

Comment: Yeah this is what I expected, I'll toss it up to incomplete translations as to my misunderstanding.　Thankyou! :)

Comment: No problem. Just as a side note, the original example is actually somewhat of an awkward phrase when paired with the translation provided in the book.
(「自分でもそれをやってみます。」 = "I'll do it by myself too.")

It would be much more natural were the Japanese / English pair found in the book to be one of the following for example:
「自分 でも それをやって**い**ます。」 = "Even I do that."
or
「自分 でも それをやってみます。」= "Even though it is I, [lowering / humbling oneself] (I) will try to do that"

Given the comment above about the book being prone to error, the example phrase itself could likewise, possibly, be incorrect.

Comment: 自分 and 一人 are different, although in English they might both translate to "oneself"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the oversight. Have edited to reflect your correction.